# Weekly raster data for temperature and precipitation in US

Tags: data-request, data.gov, weather

I am looking for weekly raster data for US for temperature and precipitation. All the major datasets PRISM, WorldClim etc. are either on a monthly scale or daily scale. I was wondering if anyone has aggregated data for weekly values from daily data or can point me to links where I can get it. I am looking for data for years 2005-2011. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here is the link from the PRISM database. You have two sections for monthly and daily data.

http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/recent/

Comment: Can you post some details for the existing daily dataset? It might be straightforward to write a small script to make weekly averages from daily measurements.

Comment: @philshem added the link.

Comment: @philshem - not so easy. The ASCII data is gridded data for conversion into raster blocks. The raster maps may be freely distributed, but the raw gridded data can only be used for non-commercial purposes. See terms of use: http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/documents/PRISM_terms_of_use.pdf

Answer (score 2):

NOAA puts out a weekly [division dataset](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/temp-and-precip/us-weekly.php) on temperature, precipitation, and drought that should answer your need.

In addition, weather radar data an be found using NOAA's [Radar Data tool](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/map/viewer/#app=cdo&cfg=radar&theme=radar&display=nexrad), and you can request data for any date range, including weekly.

There are a large number of datasets covering all areas of the world the U.S. National Oceanographic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA), which maps some of the global daily indicators including the [Global Historical Climatology Network-Daily](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/quick-links#ghcn) (GHCN-D).

International indicators of [climate change](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/climate-information/international) and data collected from many organizations are available as well.